# Is it possible to hack/automate my 2015 Honda Odyssey to keep the heat on all night, restarting the engine as needed?

Tags: electrical, electronic-control-module

Perhaps this is a good application for Arduino...

Answer (score 0):

If you run your car with the heat on (blower running) until the engine is warm, and then turn off the engine and continue running your heat blower, heat will continue coming out of the vents for just a couple of minutes. Since the engine is not running, the water pump is not circulating warm water to the heater core.

The heater core contains only a small quantity of warm water, and since it is not getting a continuous supply of warm water from the engine, the core will quickly cool off. The air coming out of the vents will become tepid and then cool, providing no heat.

You have two choices if you want heat all night: either run the engine and heat all night or run the engine and heat until the car's interior is warm, then turn off the engine and heat. When it becomes colder than you would like, start the engine and run the heat again.

That's not really "heat all night" but it can keep you from freezing.

If it is actively snowing, especially if there is wind with drifting snow, you must shovel snow away from the car's exhaust pipe, or you risk carbon monoxide poisoning.

Comment: This does not begin to address the question posed.

Comment: The question regards the creation of a device that would automatically maintain a thermostatic set point (temperature) inside the vehicle by starting and stopping the engine as necessary.

Comment: @EricHouston Exactly. No reason to answer the question, as your goal is impractical for the reasons outlined. As soon as the engine is turned off, the temperature will drop quickly due to there being no source of heat and almost no insulation. The engine would have to start again after just a few minutes, then run for a very short time. Impractical and it would cause excessive wear and tear -- much more wear and tear than running the engine continuously all night. Idling uses surprisingly little fuel, around 1/2 gallon or 2 liters per hour.

Comment: Well that is very useful information! Very useful to know that I could idle for 8 hours and use only 4 gallons of fuel! That is very surprising, since the engine puts out a tremendous amount of heat at idle, enough to be toasty warm in freezing temperatures. I am thinking that the fuel economy would be similar for running the a/c for cooling. Would you agree?

Comment: @EricHouston Remember cabin heat is waste heat that the engine has to get rid of anyway, but A/C costs additional energy. For a small engine, I think running the A/C at idle with the fan on high and temp as cold as possible would approximately double fuel consumption vs idling without A/C. But at night without solar heating, with low fan and a moderate temperature, I would expect an increase of only about 25%. Most cars increase idle speed and start the radiator fans as soon as the A/C compressor engages, and that costs fuel to spin the compressor and alternator.